# Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

Eclipse for Testers
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

I try to install TestNG but below error appeared.

"
Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse.
http://beust.com/eclipse is not a valid repository location.
"

Kindly Resolve the problems

Comment: Configuration successfully done. Solution : I have to unblocked the URL in our content blocker.

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719385/5717031

Comment: try this http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677746/5229380

Answer (score 21):

This is because http://beust.com/eclipse is redirecting to http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/ and Eclipse software seems to be not handling this URL redirection as intended.

If you add the URL as http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ then this will work OK.

Answer (score 6):

I added one "/" to the end: http://beust.com/eclipse/, then it works. If you use RAD 8+, navigate from Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections, make sure you have correct settings here, for me I have to change the setting from Native to Direct.

Answer (score 4):

Disconnect from your company's intranet network and connect to your network (Like mobile hotspot or home wifi). Try install then. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below link
https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/

The URL for downloading the Zip file is for version 6.11 in the above link. If you need a higher version try 
http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/

Comment: Thanks @Liya for giving those links. The third method given in the techbeamers website worked well for me.!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for Eclipse Neon at all. You can try to download the [zipped](http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/) archive file and add the 'update site' as an archive file from the file system.

Comment: Worked in my Eclipse Neon doing exactly what @mahishasura said

Answer (score 1):

**> Install TestNG In Eclipse IDE Via Offline Jar Files**

1. Download the latest TestNG Jar files from the link [TestNg Jars](https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/6.11.0.201703011520/site_assembly.zip)
2. Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “*dropins*” folder there.
3. Create a folder inside the *dropins* folder and name it as “testng-eclipse-6.11“
4. Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its contents to the newly created “testng-eclipse-6.11” directory.
5. Restart Eclipse

source: [techbeamers](https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a space character before or after the entry in the "Work with" field as you try to add the software site.

Other than that, the software site is perfectly valid. Perhaps the server was just down at the time you tried it. You could also check to verify that there is no proxy or firewall filtering on your end. Try pinging the site or accessing it in some other way. If Eclipse can't talk to the site, it has no way of knowing that it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are connected to the Internet
2. Key in the exact URL - http://beust.com/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

I tried Network connections -> Change native to manual -> Selected Socks and clicked on clear then I tried to install the TestNG plugin from install new software and add the URL. while installing eclipse was asking to sign in but I clicked on ok every time and installation were completed.

I tried many steps editing the eclipse.ini file etc and changing native to direct. None of those steps worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:-
Ping the URL in CMD to check if there are any loss of data packets.
So you will get clarity it is problem with your network or not ,try with different network.
Many times your antivirus or firewall block the incoming network so disable them temporarily and try.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue.

GO to Eclipse installed folder
Edit eclipse.ini file and insert
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
at the end of that file. Restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The given link is https://beust.com/eclipse
remove "s" from https & try with link http://beust.com/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I was using "http://beust.com/eclipse/" but unable to download TestNG jar it is showing no contents.

If you will use this URL "http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/" then you will able to download, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just install TestNG from below URL and no such issue will occur at latest eclipse releases:

http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Answer (score 0):

The above link didn't work it means you need a higher version of TestNG for the eclipse. Before that check TestNG is installed or not in order to know that press CTRL+N in the wizard you can see TestNG class file name.

If it is not displaying then try installing TestNG In Eclipse IDE Via Offline Jar Files:

1)Download the latest TestNG Jar files from the link TestNg Jars ("https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse")
2)Download TestNG 6.11, Clicking on the link will download the “site_assembly.zip” file for the TestNG version 6.11. This file contains two folders named as “features” and “plugins“.Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “dropins” folder there.
3)Create a folder inside the dropins folder and name it as “testng-eclipse-6.11“
4)Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its contents to the newly created “testng-eclipse-6.11” directory.
5)Restart Eclipse

OR

Go click on Help> Install new Software> Under Available software> Work with textbox paste this "2019-06 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-06" and then click on ADD. You will now see the files like TestNG and a lot many others. Select TestNG click on Next> Next> Accept the condtions> Finish. It will restart the eclipse. Inorder to know the installation is successful Press CTRL+N.