# Eclipse Mars - eclipse.org.equinox.p2.core.provisionexception

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed eclipse mars in my ***windows 8.1 Pro*** pc and its update site as below

> Mars
>
> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars
>
> The Eclipse Project Updates
>
> http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5

but when i try to reload,  it raises following [image: error]

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars.
eclipse.org.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
```

i tried following solutions but none works for me.

1. added `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in eclipse.ini
2. changed my [image: network settings] to *manual*
3. Unchecked *"contact all software sites during install to find required software"* option under install new software

**Note :** Firewall is disabled

Comment: are you able to load the update site via a browser?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker no issues in opening with browser

Answer (score 1):

This is know bug see [Bug 470900 - Eclipse Mars repository for EPP causing problems](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470900)   and [Bug 471528 - No repository found](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471528) 
Just delete delete the following:
 **`$HOME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache`** directory!

in windows:

**`C:\Users\yourusername\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache`**

Comment: windows 8.1 pro not linux or ubuntu

Comment: $HOME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache not available in windows

Comment: see the updated answer home means user directory in windows

Comment: thanks for your effort but no such directory (.eclipse) in my C:/Users/my-username . checked with hidden files too

Comment: In addition to deleting `.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache`, I had to also delete `.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/cache`.

Comment: In windows `%HOMEPATH%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache`

Answer (score 0):

Just try the same URL without the "s" secure encryption "http only"

Comment: This is about connection, Some cases this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines from your **eclipse.ini** file

-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest

-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/

Worked for me for Eclipse 2020

Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211