# Neon Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to install TestNg plugin but facing error "Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse" from Install New software link and as well as from marketplace.
I am able to open Url from internal browser and I am download plugin in eclipse Mars this issue i am facing in eclipse Neon.
I have tried all the solutions mentioned in previous post but none is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720263/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-beust-com-eclipse)

Comment: Solution mention in above post is not working for me.

Comment: This could have something to do with a *http* site redirecting to *https*. Please try the URL where it redirects to directly: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ (not a permanent solution, just troubleshooting)

Comment: cross reference to the similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847549/not-able-to-install-testng-in-eclipse-kepler

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677746/5229380

Answer (score 0):

http://beust.com/eclipse is redirecting to http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/.

Use " http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/" it will work